# Maintaining italicised words of figure caption in the List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, texmaker, report

I have a simple question but couldn’t get any online solution. I wanted to know if there is any way to keep or maintain italicised words of a figure caption the same under the List of Figures. As it stands, the List of Figures (for instance, in the LaTeX report documentclass) is not able to maintain any italicised word(s) in my figure caption. Is there any line of code to rectify this problem either manually or in an automated manner?

**PS:** The goal here is not to convert all figure captions into italics; but rather to maintain any italicised word(s) as seen in the figure caption at the List of Figures.

**For example:**

Suppose my Figure 1 caption is given as:

**Figure 1:** Infection dynamics of *Gyrodactylus* parasites.

**Question:** Is there any way to maintain the same Figure caption under the List of Figures in LaTeX; where *Gyrodactylus* will remain in italics? Thanks in advance.

I have attached a picture of the problem as a further clarification [image]

Comment: Welcome. For me, the style of the caption stays the same in the caption and the tof. Can you show us a MWE that we can see the problem you are dealing with?

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, for my case, the caption style stays the same under the figure caption and even table of contents but not under the List of Figures. The list of Figures is not able to keep italicised words in my Figure caption.

Comment: Can you provide an example showing your problem?

Comment: Maintain the italicised (emphasized) words of the captions is the default in standard article, e.g.:  `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} \listoffigures \begin{figure}\caption{a \emph{b}}  \end{figure} \end{document}`. Thus, there are something more (package, macro, template, custom class,  optional argument of caption, etc.) avoiding this behavior (without the mentioned MWE, how know what could be ...).

Comment: @ClementTwumasi Can you show us the actual code that produces the picture you showed. What is in your `preamble` and what in the `caption`?

Comment: @ClementTwumasi Have you also set the style for 'Gyrodactylus' as italic using `\emph{Gyrodactylus}` in the caption?

Comment: @Excelsior for some strange reason, your answer solved my problem. Changing `\textit{Gyrodactylus}` in my Figure caption to `\emph{Gyrodactylus}` solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

@Excelsior for some strange reason, his answer/suggestion solved my problem. Changing `\textit{Gyrodactylus}` in my Figure caption to `\emph{Gyrodactylus}` solved the problem for my case. Thank you very much.